# Access collection properties of objectforscripting object via webbrowser control

Tags: .net, winforms, com, browser

I am pulling my hair out here. I am using a WebBrowser control to host a local html page that I have (kiosk app). I have created a com visible object to use for the objectforscripting property of the webbrowser instance. All is working fine, I can call my com object from the page javascript, properties and methods. Except collection properties. Here is my code.

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
    public class TestObjectModel
    {
        public string sProp = "testprop";

        public List<string> sList = new List<string>();

        public TestObjectModel()
        {
            sList.Add("test");  
        }
     }
```

I can access sProp no problem, Below works..

```
<button onclick="alert(window.external.sProp)">test 1</button>
```

However I cannot get access to the list property.

```
<button onclick="alert(window.external.sList[0])">test 2</button>
```

I've tried converting to a hashtable, dictionary and even creating my own class that inherits from IList and marking that class comvisible. No matter what I do, I always get the error

**window.external.sList.0 is null or not an object**

help would be greatly appreciated or a direction as to what I am doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue, and using the scripting dictionary worked. [Here's a website that explains how to work with the scripting dictionary](http://tutorialsto.com/asp/base/scripting.dictionary-object.html).

I basically create another function to put the object into the scripting dictionary, and call it from there.

Remember to make the objects in the list com visible if you want to call them.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime and use a Scripting.Dictionary for your list property ?